# How can I change the default system message shown on form submission

Tags: forms, entities

I've created a business card request form as an EntityForm and am scratching my head trying to figure out where in the module i can find the line - ( " The submission has been saved " ) .

This message displays after every form submission/edit/save, and I would like to get rid of it but cant figure out where its coming from !   :)

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from [entityform_edit_form_submit](http://drupalcode.org/project/entityform.git/blob/f1c96c95ff02b9ffdf676e46d3186c70db06373d:/entityform.admin.inc)

You could try setting the translatable text string to an empty string in settings.php

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'The submission has been saved' => ''
);
```

Or else look into another way to alter drupal_set_message text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, I would recommend going to the "Form overrides" Tab of the entity form and set the Your Submissions Text and Submission Confirmation Text to ""

Answer (score -1):

Click edit and choose tab form overrides and Submission Confirmation Text. write your text.